# iOS Tab Bar question

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-bindings

based on the Tab Bar default project, I tried to build a program with 5 tabs. This part works.

On tab 2 are several labels I want to change, mostly their text. I am connecting the labels to outlets like this:

> IBOutlet UILabel* myName;

Now I can tell myName to do whatever I want. Change text for instance.
This was working when the view was on tab 1, but now on tab 2 they contain NILL at runtime. Redid all bindings after removing all, but this seems not to be the problem.

How do change labels that are on the different views a tab bar loads?

I am very sure that I oversee something fundamental, but I have no idea what this might be.

Comment: Assign them seperate names. For example, myName1,myName2 etc for each tab. Then access them depending on the tab, which you can catch using UITabBar's delegate methods.

Comment: That didnt work. I think I am missing something fundamental. Let me ask naive. (Sorry for that) Lets assume using the tab bar templete from XCode. If I want to change the label on the SecondView using a button that sets a specific text, what do I need? A button on the second view? Where would the IBAction get defined? (inside the controler, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFYI, found the bug.

A classic one: 'error sitting in fromt of screen' /Blush

I didnt setup the fileowner proper for the view. Thought I checked that, but seems not.